# Will playing a game in a Android phone while charging damage or cause harm to the battery or the phone?

Tags: battery, charging

Will the following situation damage or cause any harm to the battery or/and the phone:

- The phone is being charging (regardless it is using the electrical outlet or via USB) **and ..**
- You are playing a game while the phone is being charging **and ..**
- You will be playing the game for 5 hours or more.

In another word, if you will be playing a android game in a android phone for 5 hours or more while the android phone is being charging, will it cause any damage or harm to the android phone and/or the battery inside the android phone?

Comment: I have a case on my phone (otterbox) and it gets fairly hot while charging and playing. I think it may be trapping
heat inside the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing while charging does not damage the battery or phone directly.

The only problem is that:

battery gets warmer when is charging, and phone also gets hot when playing. So, **when you play while charging, phone gets too hot** and we know that **battery life would be affected when it works in very hot conditions.**

Sources to read more:

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_heat_and_harsh_loading_reduces_battery_life

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: Do we know that? Adding some sources would be nice.

Comment: It also make me wonder if we do it in an air-con room of 20 degree Celsius or below will prevent the heat generate by the battery to affect the battery or the phone.

Comment: The battery inside of your phone will still heat up. Ok, this will be slowed down if you do it in a 20 degree room, but eventually the effect will be the same, but it will take a little longer before the battery heats up.

Answer (score 0):

The https://android.stackexchange.com/a/54200/42449 conditions don't apply globally. It depend on hardware to hardware but it is true that using the phone for hours while charging can do damage in a way or other.

like Micromax tablets get easily heated up while charging if under use while same dont happens after a long with my sony phone.

To keep a long battery like follow the way as per above post.

Comment: "Above" and "Below" are not good references here, as they depend on how the answers are sorted (time posted, votes received, last active). So it would be best to [edit] your answer and make clear which one you're refering to (you can use the "share" link to get its URL).

Answer (score -1):

When your phone gets to 100% battery, unplug it and play games until it reaches 5% battery life remaining. Then stop playing and wait for the battery to cool. Then charge your phone again until it reaches 100%.

Comment: 5% is quite low. LiIo batteries don't like it to be "low discharged". While 5% might still be acceptable, when possible, you should connect the charger earlier (the earliest possibility after it falls below 20%, and best before it falls below 10%).

Comment: This answer is harmful, I strongly disagree with this suggestion! This wears down the battery. If the battery is fully charged, the phone will draw all needed power from the charger and leave the battery full. Charge-uncharge cycling the battery wears it down after some number of cycles (around 1000 mostly).